# "Why my definition don't change my dictionary?"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a TictacToe game for 2 Players. And when someone put its mark on low-left it crashes. And I dont know why

I checked my code several times but cant find a problem.

After playing again def playAgain does not change board and the position low-Left is always winning.

```
import sys

theBoard = {'T-L': ' ', 'T-M': ' ', 'T-R': ' ',
            'M-L': ' ', 'M-M': ' ', 'M-R': ' ',
            'L-L': ' ', 'L-M': ' ', 'L-R': ' '}

def printBoard(board):
    print('-------')
    print('|' + board['T-L'] + '|' + board['T-M'] + '|' + board['T-R'] + '|')
    print('|' + '-+-+-' + '|')
    print('|' + board['M-L'] + '|' + board['M-M'] + '|' + board['M-R'] + '|')
    print('|' + '-+-+-' + '|')
    print('|' + board['L-L'] + '|' + board['L-M'] + '|' + board['L-R'] + '|')
    print('-------')

def playAgain() :
    print('Do you want to play again?')
    again = 0
    while True:
        print('Press: Y for rematch ; E for exit')
        again = input()
        if again == 'Y':
            turn = 'X'
            theBoard = {'T-L': ' ', 'T-M': ' ', 'T-R': ' ',
            'M-L': ' ', 'M-M': ' ', 'M-R': ' ',
            'L-L': ' ', 'L-M': ' ', 'L-R': ' '}
            break
        if again == 'y':
            turn = 'X'
            theBoard = {'T-L': ' ', 'T-M': ' ', 'T-R': ' ',
            'M-L': ' ', 'M-M': ' ', 'M-R': ' ',
            'L-L': ' ', 'L-M': ' ', 'L-R': ' '}
            break
        elif again == 'E':
            sys.exit()
        elif again == 'e':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            continue


turn = 'X'

while True:
    printBoard(theBoard)
    print('Turn for ' + turn + '. Where do you want to place your ' + turn + '?')
    move=input()
    while True:
        if ' ' in theBoard[move]:
            theBoard[move] = turn
            break
        else:
            print('This spot is taken! try something else')
            print('Where do you want to place your ' + turn + '?')
            move=input()
            continue

    if turn in (theBoard['T-L'] and theBoard['T-M'] and theBoard['T-R']):
        print('Result of the game:')
        printBoard(theBoard)
        print('Player ' + turn + ' won the game!')
        playAgain()

    if turn in (theBoard['M-L'] and theBoard['M-M'] and theBoard['M-R']):
        print('Result of the game:')
        printBoard(theBoard)
        print('Player ' + turn + ' won the game!')
        playAgain()


    if turn in (theBoard['L-L'] and theBoard['L-M'] and theBoard['L-R']):
        print('Result of the game:')
        printBoard(theBoard)
        print('Player ' + turn + ' won the game!')
        playAgain()


    if turn in (theBoard['T-L'] and theBoard['M-M'] and theBoard['L-R']):
        print('Result of the game:')
        printBoard(theBoard)
        print('Player ' + turn + ' won the game!')
        playAgain()


    if turn in (theBoard['L-L'] and theBoard['M-M'] and theBoard['T-R']):
        print('Result of the game:')
        printBoard(theBoard)
        print('Player ' + turn + ' won the game!')
        playAgain()


    if turn in (theBoard['T-L'] and theBoard['M-L'] and theBoard['L-L']):
        print('Result of the game:')
        printBoard(theBoard)
        print('Player ' + turn + ' won the game!')
        playAgain()


    if turn in (theBoard['T-M'] and theBoard['M-M'] and theBoard['L-M']):
        print('Result of the game:')
        printBoard(theBoard)
        print('Player ' + turn + ' won the game!')
        playAgain()


    if turn in (theBoard['T-R'] and theBoard['M-R'] and theBoard['L-R']):
        print('Result of the game:')
        printBoard(theBoard)
        print('Player ' + turn + ' won the game!')
        playAgain()



    if turn == 'X':
        turn = '0'
    else:
        turn = 'X'
```

Comment: You should learn to debug code and need to read https://www.learnpython.org/en/Conditions to simplify your code...

Answer (score 0):

To test if a value is equal to several other values, you should use comparison chaining instead of the `and` operator, which simply performs AND operation on the values as Booleans.

Change:

```
if turn in (theBoard['T-L'] and theBoard['M-L'] and theBoard['L-L']):
```

to:

```
if turn == theBoard['T-L'] == theBoard['M-L'] == theBoard['L-L']:
```

And do the same for all the other `if` conditions.

Comment: Alright, I changed it. But know, if mark is put in corners it wins.